# .Net Core HttpContext.Request.Form Model Binding in Middleware

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have custom middleware that is auditing the request parameters of an HttpRequest.  I need to support several methods of retrieving those parameters - FromBody, FromForm, and FromQuery.  I have 1 & 3 working well, but 2 is giving me trouble with deserialization.

How can I deserialize the incoming form parameters to the type of model that is on the endpoint?  In other words, how can I mimic what the default model binder does?

I'm currently building a Dictionary<string, object> with the query and form parameters (using HttpContext.Request.Query and HttpContext.Request.Form), serializing that to a string (json), then deserializing that json to the Model Type.  This is the general idea:

```
var requestParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach(var formVariable in httpContext.Request.Form)
{
   requestParameters.Add(formVariable.Key, formVariable.Value.ToString());
}
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestParameters);
var myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(MyModel));
```

Where the models look similar to the following:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public List<Item> ListOfItems {get; set;}
}

public class Item
{
   public int ItemId {get; set;}
}
```

This works fine for primitive types, but doesn't deserialize the complex types (at least with the way they are being posted in my case).  The posted parameters look similar to this:

```
"Id" = 1
"Name" = SomeName
"ListOfItems[0].ItemId" = 1 
"ListOfItems[1].ItemId" = 2
```

The last two items do not deserialize correctly.  I don't have the option to modify the way that the post happens (i.e. post as json) since this is only for auditing, not functional changes. What option(s) do I have?

Comment: You can read request body from the  request Buffer and then you can serialize the content into your required class. Additionally, could you please share your context in more details along with your main purpose?

Comment: I have tried that as follows: 

string bodyAsString = "await new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync()", and get an empty string.  

Is that what you're referring to?